# Check if two columns are updated at same time

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to create an INSTEAD OF trigger in SQL Server to prevent two columns from being updated unless the other one is updated at the same time. Any help would be appreciated.

```
CREATE Trigger Validation1 
ON tblCust
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    <NEW.CustomerAge> = <OLD.CustomerAge> or <NEW.CustomerRange> = <OLD.CustomerRange>
    <RAISE EXCEPTION>
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question? There are plenty of resources online and in the SQL Server SSMS template explorer on how to make a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

> prevent two fields from being updated unless the other one is updated at the same time

You could  use [UPDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql)()  in after trigger or before trigger

```
IF ( UPDATE (col1) and  UPDATE (col2) )  
BEGIN  
--your logic for both col1 updated at same time
END;  
else 
begin
--other logic
end
```

As pointed out by PMB Austin in comments,you can further check inside the If logic to see ,if the updated value is same as value  and treat it based on your logic,whether you treat that as update or not

Comment: This works, but it's also possible to update to the same value... if you want to block THAT (i.e. both columns must CHANGE, not just be assigned), you can test an INNER JOIN between inserted and deleted WHERE i.col1 <> d.col1 AND i.col2 <> d.col2.